# Macs and Unix boxes can connect to Microsoft SQL backend, PCs cannot with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am running PHP in a mixed environment with Microsoft SQL Server as a back end. Devs use Macs and QA people use PCs. The problem is that the PC people have a different sql driver which uses the sqlsrv_ prefixed functions instead of mssql_ prefixed functions. I have a function which tests whether it is a PC or Mac/Unix and will call the appropriate function. Everything works on the PHP/Unix side but I cannot connect properly with Windows:

```
$serverName = "serverName; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

The exact same params work perfectly, and always have, for mssql_connect() on the Mac and Unix boxes. Can you see anything that I am doing wrong? For Windows, the $conn value always comes back as false and the errors show I cannot make a successful connection. Is there something special about sqlsrv_connect() that I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider an abstracted DB access layer like PDO.

Comment: Try specifying the port number in the server name (1433 I think is default) Definitely try for PDO, though.. if nothing else you can always try `odbc` also: http://us1.php.net/odbc

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but it's looking like more trouble than it's worth. How ironic that I can connect non-Windows boxes to MSSQL more easily. I think I am going to get Macs for our QA team in lieu of refactoring our entire code base.